# Div заезжает на div

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Есть здесь такая проблема если большой экран, то один div заезжает на другой. Уменьшал через ctrl. Помогите, а то не красиво смотрится. HELP!
http://funkyimg.com/u2/4690/520/732785fail.png
http://jsfiddle.net/sC8SH/
При большом экране или уменьшение масштаба через ctrl первый столбик залезает на второй :(

Comment: покажи код страницы и css-файла

Comment: битва экстрасенсов

Comment: Добавил в стартовый пост.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать http://jsfiddle.net/

Так людям, которые захотят вам помочь, будет меньше забот с собиранием вашего кода в единое целое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

делай ширину блоков резиновой в %

Comment: Спасиб! Помогли)